# Why google calendar event api not support IST timezone?

Tags: java, google-calendar-api

we have 2 request of google calendar event get API.

why? second request gives us bad request why 1st not?

google calendar is in IST timezone only.

first,

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events? 
    timeMin=2019-07-27T14:30:00-0400&timeMax=2019-09-07T14:29:59- 
    0400&timeZone=America/New_York
```

second,

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events? 
    timeMin=2019-07-28T00:00:00+0530&timeMax=2019-09- 
    07T01:59:59+0530&timeZone=Asia/Calcutta
```

first request output is - 200 status ok.

It gives output for second request 400 status

Is their any wrong? please correct us

Answer (score 0):

I thik you have a typo in a spelling of Calcutta.
Try using "Asia/Kolkata"

Comment: agreed Asia/Kolkata  http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zonehelp.tzc?cc=IN&ccdesc=India

Comment: Their is only one solution i got where need to provide only UTC time like timeMin=2019-08-27T00:00:00.000z and timeZone= "" what u want. then response include the input timezone time